# Override the compiler attribute in an Ant javac task

Tags: ant

I'm trying to override Ant compiler attributes via the command line so that all 'javac' tasks use my specified compiler.
The problem I've run into is that any target that sets its own value for compiler overrides the one that I set at the commmand line.  So, even though I'm entering the following command.

```
ant -Dbuild.compiler=mycompiler
```

Any target that has the following is going to use the modern compiler instead of mycompiler because of that compiler="modern" attribute

```
<javac srcdir="."  
       destdir="${classes.dir}/core"  
       compiler="modern"  
       encoding="UTF-8">  
    <include name="org/**" />  
    <include name="com/**" />  
    <compilerarg line="${config.build.compilerarg}" />  
</javac>
```

Is there any way to override this from the command line, or am I stuck editing the build file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Ant [`javac` task documentation](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html) says:

> It is possible to use different compilers. This can be specified by either setting the global build.compiler property, which will affect all  tasks throughout the build, or by setting the compiler attribute, specific to the current  task. Valid values for either the build.compiler property or the compiler attribute are:

It sounds as if you can ***either*** specify the global build.compiler property **or** set a specific compiler attribute.

So, it looks like you will need to modify your build file and either:

1. remove the compiler attribute from the javac calls and allow the
   global build.compiler setting to
   cascade down
2. change the values of the compiler
   attribute from a hard-coded string
       **compiler="modern"** to be property
       **compiler="${javac.compiler}"**