# How to set JDK version in Gradle project WITHOUT explicit JDK path?

Tags: java, gradle, path

When we set path to java libraries, we just write something like this:

```
compile('ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.0.13')
```

There is no any path information here, I don't bother if JAR will be located on drive `C:` on drive `D:` or in Linux root `/`

Let it remains so.

And now I want to set JDK version. I wish to be able to change this version easily and portable without setting any paths, relative to my machine.

Is this possible?

**UPDATE**

Apparently, even Ant can this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11551770/258483

Answer (score -1):

> Java has no concept of libraries or versions. In Java, there is no
>   standard way to tell the JVM that you are using version 3.0.5 of
>   Hibernate, and there is no standard way to say that foo-1.0.jar
>   depends on bar-2.0.jar. This has led to external solutions often based
>   on build tools.

This is taken from [Gradle's dependency management Doc.](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html)

So this is where gradle dependency management is done, by dependency they mean Project's dependencies on external packages. Something called Separation of Concern. If you want to declare which Jdk your project should be using (jdk here is the compiler (the javac program) which is doing something thats logically different than what Project's dependencies do) the dependency block is not the right place to put it in.

As for how to declare the your custom jdk path to use:

Two ways

1. In `gradle.properties` in the `.gradle` directory in your `HOME_DIRECTORY` set `org.gradle.java.home=/path_to_jdk_directory`
   The gradle.properties can be defined at project level too, see gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html
2. In your `gradle.build`

   ```
   compileJava.options.fork = true
   compileJava.options.forkOptions.executable = /path_to_javac
   ```

Comment: This way I can't share project with other developers, for example, share between Windows, Linux and Mac, since JDK paths are completely different on three platforms. So, this way is not applicable.

Comment: JDK is not just a compiler, it contains plenty of JARs, which are also have versions, sometimes incompatible.

Comment: Also I can propose very simple way to overcome your yellow cite: just configure JDK at some machine-level config file. This way developers could configure several JDKs at their machine level, while retail no path dependent information at project level. Is this possible in Gradle?

Comment: Also changing JDK globally at user level is not applicable since it will remove possibility to compile different projects with different JDKs

Comment: I think for gradle scripts to even start executing most of its functionalities (that are coded in java) it will need the jdk to compile and the jre to run, so no matter what gradle will need to know the path to the jdk folder/dir