# ant build.compiler usage

Tags: java, ant, javac

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Override the compiler attribute in an Ant javac task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/235363/override-the-compiler-attribute-in-an-ant-javac-task)

In Ant, how exactly do I use the `build.compiler` option, or [the `<javac>` task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html)'s `compiler` attribute?

I tried setting `compiler="javac1.5"`, but when I opened the resulting class-file in a hex editor, the class version was still shown as `32` hex (version 1.6) — until I set `JAVA_HOME` to point to my JDK 1.5 installation. (Until then, it had been pointing to my JDK 1.6 installation.) So it seems like `JAVA_HOME` supersedes the `compiler` attribute — in which case, what is the purpose of that attribute?

The `source` and `target` attributes *do* seem to work correctly; when I specify the `target` version, the resulting class-file does have the right version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The purpose of the attribute is to be able to choose something like `gcj` or `jikes` instead of the standard JDK compiler.  `javac1.5` (and `javac1.6` etc.) is just an alias for `modern`, the standard compiler, and is defined simply to support the rule that the default value of `build.compiler` is `javac1.x` with `x` matching the running JDK (so the default is `modern` on 1.3 and higher and `classic` on 1.2 and below).

If you want to compile classes that will run on 1.5 then you need to use `source="1.5" target="1.5"` and also set the bootstrap classpath to point to a 1.5 class library, to ensure you aren't calling methods that were introduced in 1.6 or later.

Comment: I sense the asker wanted to know how to set and where to set the build.compiler property.  This is because there are several references across the internet to build.properties but I have found nowhere which explains how to use build.properties.  Indeed, this is what has brought me to this question.  For this reason also, I do not feel this question is a duplicate!  My guess at the answer is to use the ant <property> task something like this:  <property name="build.compiler" value="javac1.5"/>.  Am I correct?  As this question has been marked as a duplicate, I cannot offer my answer.